# How to resolve HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

Tags: .net, sql-server, iis

I know that this question have been asked a lot, but none of the answers helped me.

What's happening is that I'm publishing my `.net 5` application on `IIS` on an Azure VM.
The problem is when connecting to database server on the VM.

Using an Azure SQl Server with the following connection string, is working normally:

```
Server=tcp:serverName.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=database;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=username;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

But using a connection string for a SQL Server that existing on the VM such as the following:

```
Server=ACS;Initial Catalog=database;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=username;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Is causing the following error:

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

Anyone have any idea what's happening?? I think it's something related to security, permissions on the SQL Server installed on the VM machine. Or that I should add a port number to the connection string.

Comment: Does it work with `Server=(local)`?

Comment: Nope, I've tried (local), ., and still doing the same thing. It's like I don't have permission to access the server or the database. But It's weird, because when I open `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio` and I use the same username and password, I can login to the server normally!

Comment: When you use SSMS, are you using from a remote session on the VM or on your local machine?  Do you have the appropriate network providers enabled on the SQL Server instance (tcp/ip for example)?

Comment: Yes I do, and I'm accessing the VM with a RDP (Remote Desktop Connection).

Comment: By default SQL Server is installed with self-signed X.509 certificates. Unless you've installed your own CA-signed certificate, or you've exported the public key and added it to your Trusted Roots store, you'll probably want to use `TrustServerCertificate=True;` instead.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning It worked, thank you. You can add your comment as an answer please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default SQL Server is installed with self-signed X.509 certificates. Unless you've installed your own CA-signed certificate, or you've exported the public key and added it to your Trusted Roots store, you'll probably want to use `TrustServerCertificate=True;` instead.